# How to get BooleanBinding from comparing 2 DatePickers?

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker, javafx-8, javafx-bindings

I have two `DatePicker`s and one `Button` on the GUI. I need to disable the button whenever the first datePicker has a date that is *NOT* before the second datePicker's date. i.e. `before` is `false` in the following snippet:

```
LocalDate date1 = dpFromDate.getValue();
LocalDate date2 = dpToDate.getValue();
boolean before = date1.isBefore(date2);
button.setDisable(!before);
```

using Bindings APIs.

```
BooleanBinding bb = ???;
button.disableProperty().bind(bb);
```

---

Here is my working solution, but I believe there is a better API to handle such situation:

```
BooleanBinding bb = Bindings.selectInteger(dpFromDate.valueProperty(), "year")
         .greaterThanOrEqualTo(Bindings.selectInteger(dpToDate.valueProperty(), "year"));

bb = bb.or(
       Bindings.selectInteger(dpFromDate.valueProperty(), "year")
       .isEqualTo(Bindings.selectInteger(dpToDate.valueProperty(), "year"))
  .and(Bindings.selectInteger(dpFromDate.valueProperty(), "monthValue")
       .greaterThanOrEqualTo(Bindings.selectInteger(dpToDate.valueProperty(), "monthValue")))
   );

bb = bb.or(
       Bindings.selectInteger(dpFromDate.valueProperty(), "year")
       .isEqualTo(Bindings.selectInteger(dpToDate.valueProperty(), "year"))
  .and(Bindings.selectInteger(dpFromDate.valueProperty(), "monthValue")
      .isEqualTo(Bindings.selectInteger(dpToDate.valueProperty(), "monthValue")))
  .and(Bindings.selectInteger(dpFromDate.valueProperty(), "dayOfMonth")
      .greaterThanOrEqualTo(Bindings.selectInteger(dpToDate.valueProperty(), "dayOfMonth")))
   );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a `BooleanBinding` depending on the `DatePicker` values that compares both dates. This way you don't have to write the functionality yourself and even more important - you don't need to create such a complicated binding:

```
BooleanBinding bb = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
    LocalDate from = dpFromDate.getValue();
    LocalDate to = dpToDate.getValue();

    // disable, if one selection is missing or from is not smaller than to
    return (from == null || to == null || (from.compareTo(to) >= 0));
}, dpFromDate.valueProperty(), dpToDate.valueProperty());

button.disableProperty().bind(bb);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for +1.